# Android : "android.support.v4.widget" vs "android.widget"

Tags: android, widget, android-support-library

I don't know the difference among that.
I only know "android.support.v4.widget" aide from API 4 to later.

Regards!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/package-summary.html

Comment: I think the first package comes with few other widgets which could not be found originally in the android.widget

Answer (score 1):

Support package can wear on versions prior to 4.0, widgets and functionalities introduced with it.

If you do develop your application for versions 4.0 and earlier (2.3 for example), you must use the support package rather than the traditional widgets to avoid runtime errors on these versions.

Comment: It is *not* Android version 4.0, it is version 4 of the support libraries, which target API level 9 (Android 2.3). Or SL 13, which targets API 13 (Android 3.2). https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#v4